# get link of img in div#imgTagWrapperId

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, src, rvest

I want the extract just the link of an image as a string using rvest in R

What I have tried is:

```
url <-"https://www.amazon.in/Livwell-Multipurpose-MultiColor-Polka- 
Lunch/dp/B07LGTPM3D/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1548701326&sr=8-1- 
spons&keywords=lunch+bag&psc=1"

webpage <- read_html(url)
imglink<-(webpage %>%
html_nodes("div#imgTagWrapperId") %>% 
html_nodes("img") %>%
html_attr("src"))
```

I expect imglink to have the value: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51H-DAUxWzL.jpg

However, it is a very long character type object which is not what I require.
Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the id (and attribute) shown below or extract from script tag (via converting to json the javascript object inside the tag)

```
require(rvest)
url <-"https://www.amazon.in/Livwell-Multipurpose-MultiColor-Polka-Lunch/dp/B07LGTPM3D/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1548701326&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=lunch+bag&psc=1"

webpage <- read_html(url)
r <- webpage %>%
            html_nodes("#landingImage") %>% 
            html_attr("data-a-dynamic-image")
imglink <- strsplit(r, '"')[[1]][2]
print(imglink)
```

Comment: another follow up question: how can i alter this to reference the other images i.e. there are 5 other images of the same product - many thanks

Comment: do you mind opening a new question, stating what those links are? First check that they are all present in the response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55819596/extract-links-of-subsequent-images-in-divdata-old-hires posted it here